# Kotlin mutableListOf with several entries

Tags: kotlin

I want to to fill a list with several entries. So far I only have one entry:

```
val someAttributes: List<Product.MyAttribute> = mutableListOf(Product.MyAttribute("ATTRIBUTE A", listOf("3")))
```

This is MyAttribute:

```
  data class MyAttribute(
    var key: String = "",
    var values: List<String> = ArrayList()
  )
```

What's the correct syntax in Kotlin to add several entries to a mutableList?

Comment: You can add as many arguments in  `mutableListOf`  as you like. e.g. `mutableListOf(a,b,c,d)` . Refer to the official [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-list-of.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
val someAttributes = mutableListOf(
  Product.MyAttribute("ATTRIBUTE A", listOf("3")),
  Product.MyAttribute("ATTRIBUTE B", listOf("4")),
  Product.MyAttribute("ATTRIBUTE C", listOf("5"))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`add`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/add.html) for a single item, or [`addAll`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/add-all.html) if you have several. You can pass in an index to say where you want them inserted, otherwise they're added to the end of the list

```
someAttributes.add(newAttr)
someAttributes.addAll(listOf(coolAttr, radAttr))
```

If you just want to add them all when you initialise the list, just pass them all in as parameters - [`mutableListOf` takes a `vararg`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-list-of.html), i.e. a variable number of arguments (you just separate them with commas)

```
someAttributes = mutableListOf(attr1, attr2, attr3)
```